# Insert into … values ( SELECT … FROM … ) in postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select, insert

I am working with `Postgresql` database. I have one database which is - `db1` and I have one table inside this database which is `App1`.

I need to make a select query against this `App1` table which is in `db1` and then whatever results I am getting back, I need to insert them in `App2` table as it is which is in another database `db2`.

Below is my query which I am running against `App1` table which is in `db1` -

```
select col1, col2 from App1 limit 5
```

Now is there any way I can use Insert statement along with above SELECT statement which can insert into App2 table for me automatically which is in `db2`?

Something along this line -

```
Insert into … values ( SELECT … FROM … )
```

Is this possible to do in Postgresql as both the tables are in different database?

Comment: really? is it so very hard to look at the postgres docs? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-insert.html

Comment: @MarcB: But both of the tables are in different database so this will still work?

Comment: as long as the user you're running this under has the appropriate rights, postgres won't care.

Comment: `select db1.table1.field, db2.table2.otherfield` is perfectly legitimate SQL in pretty much any sql database worth using.

Comment: @MarcB: please don't link to outdated versions (you can use `current` instead of the version number in the URL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this between databases you must use [the foreign data wrapper `postgres_fdw`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html) or [use `dblink`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html). See the documentation. PostgreSQL doesn't support cross-database `SELECT`.

Often, if you find yourself wanting to do this, you should be using separate schemas in a single database instead.

---

BTW, it's generally:

```
INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...
```

i.e. there's no subquery, no parentheses. That's because the `VALUES` clause is actually a standalone statement too:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...
```

observe:

```
regress=> VALUES (1,2), (2,3);
 column1 | column2 
---------+---------
       1 |       2
       2 |       3
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.. So what should I do for my use case? Should I get the data from db1 and put it in response object and then iterate the object and then insert into db2?

Comment: You can do it via the client side as you describe, or you can use dblink or postgres_fdw, as I linked to above, to do it via an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query